# glDrawElementsInstanced rendering always rendering the last instance at the origin

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm in the process of adding instanced rendering to my engine, to do this I'm adding an offset attribute with a divisor of 1. But for whatever reason, OpenGL is consistently rendering 1 instance at the origin and missing the very last instance (or putting the last instance at the origin).

Say I have the offset buffer filled with `{{1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},{2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f},{3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f}}`, then I end up getting objects rendered at (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), (2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f) and (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)... which is clearly wrong.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec4 vPosition;
in vec3 offset;
uniform mat4 projview;
smooth out vec4 fColor;
void main()
{
    vec4 fPosition = projview * vec4(offset + vPosition.xyz, vPosition.w);
    fPosition.z = 0;
    gl_Position = fPosition;
    fColor = vec4(gl_InstanceID/3.0f, gl_InstanceID/3.0f, gl_InstanceID/3.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
smooth in vec4 fColor;
out vec4 pColor;
void main()
{
    pColor = fColor;
}
```

I have triple checked that the buffers are loading all the data correctly (going as far as using glGetBufferSubData), and that seems to be fine, which tells me either OpenGL is broken (unlikely), or there's something wrong with this:

```
// vPosition
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0x0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0x0, 0x4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0x10, 0x0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(0x0, 0x0);

// offset
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0x1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0x1, 0x4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0xC, 0x0);
glVertexAttribDivisor(0x1, 0x1);

glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_LINES, 0x6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0x0, 0x3);
```

I'm putting the following into the buffers (which again, I have triple checked):

vPosition buffer:

```
vector<glm::vec4> {
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}
};
```

index buffer:

```
vector<GLuint> {0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3};
```

offset buffer:

```
vector<glm::vec3> {
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    {2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f},
    {3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f}
};
```

It ends up looking like this (note, black: gl_InstanceID = 0, white: gl_InstanceID = 2):

[image]

[image]

Gif of this happening with a different model:

[image]

Comment: You say there are 4 components in the attribute even though you build them from vec3s. You pass stride == 8 while sizeof(glm::vec3) == 12. (Not sure if that will fix the issue)

Comment: Whoops, that was a slip up in translation (pulled the wrong value out of Visual Studio). It _was_ actually 12

Comment: I was definitely reading the size wrong though. I thought `glGetVertexAttribiv(i, GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_SIZE, &size);` returned the size it was _meant_ to be, but apparently it returns the size it's currently set to (defaults to 4). Is there a fast way to translate GL_FLOAT_VEC2/3/4 etc from`glGetActiveAttrib` into GL_FLOAT + size needed for `glVertexAttribPointer`?